# Why httpwebrequest of C# is returning non compressed response

Tags: c#

I am building one auto login application for one of my website. I have developed the auto login tool in C#. I have used httpwebrequest to make post call on the login page. I'm facing issue with the compression of the webpage. In some of the computers I'm not getting compressed response while in others I'm getting the response. Can anyone suggest how I can guaranteed get compressed response. The following is the code I have written for my httpwebrequest:

```
httpRequest.Connection = "keepalive";
httpRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate, br");
httpRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
httpRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows T 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36";
httpRequest.UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing = true;            
httpRequest.Headers.Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); 
httpRequest.Method = "POST";
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postdata);
httpRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
requestStream.Flush();
requestStream.Close();
response = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
HttpWebResponse response2 = response;  
switch (response2.StatusCode)
{
    case HttpStatusCode.OK:      
         responseStream = response2.GetResponseStream();                        
         if (response2.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("gzip"))
         {
            str = new StreamReader(new GZipStream(responseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress), Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();
         }
         else if (response2.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("deflate"))
         {
             str = new StreamReader(new DeflateStream(responseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress), Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();
         }
         else
         {
              str = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();
          }              
          responseStream.Close();
          responseStream = null;
    break;
 }
```